# Derivative of a symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, calculus-and-analysis

I need to write an elasticity equations as:

```
{{a*∂/∂x,b*∂/∂y},{c*∂/∂x,d*∂/∂y},{e*∂/∂y,f*∂/∂x}}.{{u},{v}}
```

where `a,b,...,f` are constants and `u, v` are two functions of `x` and `y`. In the other words, I would like to write `D.U`, where `D` is the differential operator matrix and `U` is the objective function.

Can you help me out on this, please?

Answer (score 10):

The dot product (`Dot`) in *Mathematica* is defined as that (discrete) inner product for which the first operation is multiplication and the second, addition. So, you cannot use a dot product directly here, because it cannot incorporate concepts of differentiation or functional application. Instead, you should use a suitably constructed generalized inner product.

First we construct your differential operator matrix (we call it `m`, because `D` is already taken for *Mathematica*'s own partial derivative function). Let's do this as

```
m = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}.{∂/∂x, ∂/∂y}
```

just to make the point clearer. Note that we do not need to have the differential operator as a "column vector"--*Mathematica* lacks the concept of different "directions" of vector, because it operates in the domain of general tensors, rather than being based on matrix operations. In this sense a vector is truly a one-dimensional object, rather than a $1 \times n$ or $n \times 1$ matrix. You can leave out the extra levels of `List`.

In *Mathematica* the code will be:

```
m = Inner[
  Function[\[FormalF], #1 D[\[FormalF], #2]] &,
  {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, {x, y},
  List
 ];
```

It gives

> [image: differential operator]

which is what you wrote above. Now we can apply this to your `U`, which is just:

```
Inner[#1[#2] &, m, {u, v}, Plus]
```

Let's take $u = \cos{x} + 3x^2$ and $v = e^{1 \over {1 + y}}$ as an example:

```
With[{u = Cos[x] + 3 x^2, v = Exp[1/(1 + y)]},
  Inner[#1[#2] &, m, {u, v}, Plus]
 ]
```

> [image: result of applying differential operator]

I think this is along the lines of what you were after. Please note that, although they are shown as scalars here, `u` and `v` can also be vector-valued functions without any change in the code.